# Get NSWindow from kCGWindowNumber

Tags: objective-c, nswindow, nsapplication, always-on-top

From k`CGWindowNumber`, how do I get `NSWindow` ref.
I tried using:

```
[NSApp windowWithWindowNumber:windowNumber]
```

but I always get a null value.
I need to get the `NSWindow` to apply `[window setlevel:NSFloatingWindowLevel]`, that I have set the always on top of a given window.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem or has any alternative solution?

---

Thanks for the answer, but this is not the solution, I had already tried but it does not work, actually I did a test , 
I tried the following code:

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i <10000; i + +) {
NSWindow * wind;
wind = [NSApp windowWithWindowNumber: windowNumber];
NSLog (@ "\ n Window:% @", wind);
}
```

but the result is always the `Window: (null)`

I have a list of window, where can i get OwnerPid Number of window ecc.. ecc... and now  I need to set the always on top of some windows.

The Always on top is possible set whit: `[window setlevel:NSFloatingWindowLevel]`, window is a `NSwindow` object, it's real?

Do you have a solution? or another idea , for my problem?

Comment: Where are you getting the window number from?

Answer (score 2):

`kCGWindowNumber` is a `CFNumber`/`NSNumber`, `-windowWithWindowNumber:` expects an `NSInteger`. You'll need to extract the integer out of the window number reference (with `-integerValue`) before passing it to `-windowWithWindowNumber:`.

Comment: This works only for windows that belong to the application which call it. But for others `[NSApp windowWithWindowNumber:[[[NSWindow windowNumbersWithOptions:NSWindowNumberListAllApplications] objectAtIndex:i] integerValue]];` returns nil. Why?

Comment: The documentation for `windowWithWindowNumber:` says: "may return `nil` for window numbers found using `windowNumbersWithOptions:` if there is no corresponding window object **owned by your app**".

Comment: oops... missed that... need some other solution

Comment: @Garnik did you find something ?

Comment: @AmitHooda I am sorry, this was 8 years ago and unfortunately I don't work there anymore. Eventually I even don't remember how I solved that issue. Sorry