# CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo returns info with kCGWindowSharingState set to 0

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I am trying to get the `kCGWindowSharingState` value for a window from another process.

I created a new project and and set the `NSWindow.sharingType` to `NSWindowSharingReadWrite`.

I created another project and from that project I am running the following code to get the value of `kCGWindowSharingState`:

```c
CFArrayRef windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);
NSLog(@"windowList: %@", windowList);
```

It returns an array of dictionaries with the `kCGWindowSharingState` value, but it's always set to `0`.

Any help regarding this would be good. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did edit your question to make it more clear what you're asking for and replied. Let me know if my edit is wrong and you asked for something else.

Comment: @zrzka it made a mess, things got messed up with the edit :) , i don't want to get the sharingtype, the issues is sharingtype is always 0 in other process, even if i set it to NSWindowSharingReadWrite or NSWindowSharingReadOnly

Comment: I can also add sample code of projects if anyone needs it.

Comment: I don't get it. You say _I don't want to get the sharingtype_ and then _the issues is sharingtype is always 0 in other process_ which means that you're getting it and checking the value. No need to add sample code, as I wrote in the answer, your _another project_ must have screen recording permissions otherwise the `kCGWindowSharingState` will be always be `0` no matter what you set in the first project.

Comment: i want information from CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo api and its not the sharingtype its named as kCGWindowSharingState so that might have got you confused.

Comment: Just to clarify `sharingType` & `kCGWindowSharingState` -  `NSWindow.sharingType` value == `kCGWindowSharingState` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *another project* must have screen recording permissions. Is there an API to ask for them? No. You have to try to record a screen to get the system dialog.

```c
- (BOOL)doWeHaveScreenRecordingPermissions {
    // Try to record -> triggers system dialog
    CGDisplayStreamRef stream = CGDisplayStreamCreate(CGMainDisplayID(), 1, 1, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, nil, ^(CGDisplayStreamFrameStatus status, uint64_t displayTime, IOSurfaceRef frameSurface, CGDisplayStreamUpdateRef updateRef) {
    });

    // NULL = No permissions
    BOOL result = stream != NULL;

    if (stream) {
        CFRelease(stream);
    }

    return result;
}
```

You can use `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo` without these permissions, but the value for the `kCGWindowSharingState` will always be `0`. Correct value will be returned once your another app gains these permissions.

Briefly discussed in the [WWDC 2019 - Advances in macOS Security](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/701/?time=858).

This security dance applies to `kCGWindowSharingState` & `kCGWindowName`.

---

My application delegate:

```c
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSLog(@"Screen Recording permissions: %@", [self doWeHaveScreenRecordingPermissions] ? @"Yay!" : @"N/A");

    CFArrayRef windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);
    if (windowList == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    CFIndex count = CFArrayGetCount(windowList);
    for (CFIndex index = 0 ; index < count ; index++) {
        CFDictionaryRef windowInfo = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(windowList, index);

        CFStringRef owner = CFDictionaryGetValue(windowInfo, kCGWindowOwnerName);
        if (owner == NULL) {
            continue;
        }

        if (CFStringCompare(owner, CFSTR("ShareWindow"), 0) != kCFCompareEqualTo) {
            continue;
        }

        NSLog(@"Got a window from ShareWindow! %@", windowInfo);
    }

    CFRelease(windowList);
}
```

**No screen recording permissions**

```
2020-06-03 13:22:36.073581+0200 GetSharedWindow[54889:828225] Screen Recording permissions: N/A
2020-06-03 13:22:36.074951+0200 GetSharedWindow[54889:828225] Got a window from ShareWindow! {
    kCGWindowAlpha = 1;
    kCGWindowBounds =     {
        Height = 292;
        Width = 480;
        X = 235;
        Y = 538;
    };
    kCGWindowIsOnscreen = 1;
    kCGWindowLayer = 0;
    kCGWindowMemoryUsage = 1152;
    kCGWindowNumber = 5672;
    kCGWindowOwnerName = ShareWindow;
    kCGWindowOwnerPID = 54445;
    kCGWindowSharingState = 0;         <-----
    kCGWindowStoreType = 1;
}
```

**Screen recording permissions**

```
2020-06-03 13:24:33.823247+0200 GetSharedWindow[55697:832599] Screen Recording permissions: Yay!
2020-06-03 13:24:33.824580+0200 GetSharedWindow[55697:832599] Got a window from ShareWindow! {
    kCGWindowAlpha = 1;
    kCGWindowBounds =     {
        Height = 292;
        Width = 480;
        X = 235;
        Y = 538;
    };
    kCGWindowIsOnscreen = 1;
    kCGWindowLayer = 0;
    kCGWindowMemoryUsage = 1152;
    kCGWindowName = Window;
    kCGWindowNumber = 5672;
    kCGWindowOwnerName = ShareWindow;
    kCGWindowOwnerPID = 54445;
    kCGWindowSharingState = 2;         <-----
    kCGWindowStoreType = 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have given all the the permissions to both the projects. But it still gives me 0 when asked from CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo api

Comment: from the above api only window server & dock have kCGWindowSharingState as 1 which means NSWindowSharingReadOnly and i could not find any example of using NSWindowSharingReadOnly when its set from one application and read from other application

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong, see my updated answer with code & output.

Comment: thanks i found the mistake, actually i was thinking that accessiblity permission was needed but there is a runtime permission which is required now. Thanks for the help. I have upvoted and accepted the ans. One quick question though can i get NSWindow from the window number if the shareing state is 1 or 2 and set some parameters to that NSWindow ?

Comment: Only if it's _your_ window, see this answer for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31890095/581190. Be aware that comments are not for additional questions, you should create a new one. Search for accessibility questions on SO if you'd like modify some properties of the window (move it, ...).

Comment: Yes i understand that SO is not for additional questions in comments, either we could move in chat or ask another question, but there is one thing missing how i can't tag any user there in comments so as to ask to particular user.

Comment: I know how to do when its my own app, but the think is i have multiple apps in my bundle, so its my app but in a way its completely another app so can i have something like that in that case.

Comment: I have asked another question if you can help me with that here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62178732/showing-one-nswindow-from-one-nsapplication-on-top-of-another-nswindow-from-nsap